# json schema validation patternProperties and properties conflict

Tags: javascript, json, jsonschema

i 've this JSON schema

```
{
  "title": "JSON Schema for revues subscribtion",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "lab": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "patternProperties": {
    "[A-Za-z][A-Za-z_]*[A-Za-z]": {
      "type": "boolean"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "lab"
  ]
}
```

i want to match a json data like

```
{
 "SP": false,
 "lab": "labri"
}
```

but it failed because `"lab"` value is expected as `boolean`. that's mean `"lab"` is matched by the **patternProperties**.

Do someone have a solution for this ?

*PS : Sorry i'm not good at english*

Comment: Which keys do you want to be boolean? Could you provide any example? As defined in patternProperties the behavior is as expected.

Comment: All keys matching this regex `[A-Za-z][A-Za-z_]*[A-Za-z]` excluding 'lab'. 'lab' is the key defining a company and the other key (with boolean value) define if a service is enabled for the company 

`{
 "SP": false,
 "lab": "labri"
}`
for example here, the lab 'labri' have the service 'SP' disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use regexp that would match what you need but won't match 'lab'. At best it is not trivial.

Another is this schema:

```
{
    "title" : "JSON Schema for revues subscribtion",
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
        "lab" : { "type" : "string" }
    },
    "additionalProperties" : { "type": "boolean" },
    "required" : [ "lab" ]
}
```

It will require all properties but lab to be boolean. I don't think you can do any better.